# Avoid matching .WillOnce multiple times in Google Mock

Tags: c++, tdd, googlemock

I have a mock object setup that looks like this:

```
MyObject obj;
EXPECT_CALL(obj, myFunction(_))
.WillOnce(Return(1))
.WillOnce(Return(1))
.WillOnce(Return(1))
.WillRepeatedly(Return(-1));
```

Is there a way to not have to repeat `.WillOnce(Return(1))` three times?

Comment: BTW: You're not _'running'_ but _'matching'_ `Return(x)`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

##### You can use `.Times(nn)` followed by `.WillRepeatedly(...` to solve this:

```
using testing::InSequence;

MyObject obj;

{
  InSequence s;
  EXPECT_CALL(obj, myFunction(_))
      .Times(3)
      .WillRepeatedly(Return(1));
  EXPECT_CALL(obj, myFunction(_))
      .WillRepeatedly(Return(-1));
}
```

Comment: Ah! Didn't know these can be combined this way. That looks much easier than my proposal :-) ...

Comment: or `EXPECT_CALL(...).WillRepeatedly(Return(-1)); EXPECT_CALL(...).Times(3).WillRepeatedly(Return(1).RetiresOnSaturation();` which looks a little overkill here, but there are other cases where it could be helpful.

Comment: Currently this function executes only 2 times for my code

Answer (score 4):

For completeness' sake, there's another standard/simple option, though the accepted answer seems clearer in this case.

```
EXPECT_CALL(obj, myFunction(_)).WillRepeatedly(Return(-1));
EXPECT_CALL(obj, myFunction(_)).Times(3).WillRepeatedly(Return(1)).RetiresOnSaturation();
```

This can be useful if you know what you want your last/default response to be (`-1`), but want to muck with the number of times its called before then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no other way to configure this behavior. Can't find an obvious way in the documentation at least.

You'll might get off this problem introducing an appropriate [user defined matcher](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md#defining-matchers) though, that keeps track of a calling count and threshold you can provide from your testcases via template parameters (don't actually know how to induce the `ResultType` automatically :-( ):

```
using ::testing::MakeMatcher;
using ::testing::Matcher;
using ::testing::MatcherInterface;
using ::testing::MatchResultListener;

template
    < unsigned int CallThreshold
    , typename ResultType
    , ResultType LowerRetValue
    , ResultType HigherRetValue
    >
class MyCountingReturnMatcher 
: public MatcherInterface<ResultType>
{
public:
    MyCountingReturnMatcher()
    : callCount(0)
    {
    }

    virtual bool MatchAndExplain
        ( ResultType n
        , MatchResultListener* listener
        ) const 
    {
        ++callCount;
        if(callCount <= CallThreshold)
        {
            return n == LowerRetValue;
        }

        return n == HigherRetValue;
    }

    virtual void DescribeTo(::std::ostream* os) const 
    {
        if(callCount <= CallThreshold)
        {
            *os << "returned " << LowerRetValue;
        }
        else
        {
            *os << "returned " << HigherRetValue;
        }
    }

    virtual void DescribeNegationTo(::std::ostream* os) const 
    {
        *os << " didn't return expected value ";
        if(callCount <= CallThreshold)
        {
            *os << "didn't return expected " << LowerRetValue 
                << " at call #" << callCount;
        }
        else
        {
            *os << "didn't return expected " << HigherRetValue 
                << " at call #" << callCount;
        }
    }

private:
    unsigned int callCount;
};

template
    < unsigned int CallThreshold
    , typename ResultType
    , ResultType LowerRetValue
    , ResultType HigherRetValue
    >
inline Matcher<ResultType> MyCountingReturnMatcher() 
{
    return MakeMatcher
               ( new MyCountingReturnMatcher
                    < ResultType
                    , CallThreshold 
                    , ResultType
                    , LowerRetValue
                    , HigherRetValue
                    >()
               );
}
```

Use then to expect a certainly counted call result:

```
EXPECT_CALL(blah,method)
   .WillRepeatedly(MyCountingReturnMatcher<1000,int,1,-1>()) // Checks that method
                                                             // returns 1000 times 1
                                                             // but -1 on subsequent 
                                                             // calls.
```

**NOTE**
I didn't check this code to be working as intended, but it should guide you into the right direction.